# Sandbox account for iOS Test flight beta testing

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, testflight

Do I need to create Sandbox account additionally when I test through test-flight beta testing?. I heard that In-app purchases we can test directly  from test-flight beta testing without creating sandbox account. Is it true?

Explaining test-flight beta testing in much detail might be helpful.

Comment: You just need an Apple ID in order to test your application with TestFlight.
You can then create a list of people who will test your application and receive a TestFlight notification when you will press the button "go".

Answer (score 5):

TestFlight users don't require a sandbox account, but they will test against an automatically created sandbox account.

The moment a tester opens your application, a sandbox account is created for them. This means it's no longer necessary to create test accounts in iTunes Connect. Testing In-App Purchases was never easier.

[Source](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224)

Note that your TestFlight user is a legitimate App Store user. That user will be purchasing, restoring, etc. from the IAP in the Sandbox as opposed to the real IAP.

goto **iTunesConnect >> Users and Roles >> Sandbox testers >>** add give this test accounts credentials to all testers for testing IAP or make many testing account.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a Sandbox account for TestFlight beta testing. Valid Apple accounts can be used to test IAP in TestFlight beta testing. If you are using adhoc builds to test IAP you need sandbox accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an Apple ID in order to test your application with TestFlight.
You can then create a list of people who will test your application and receive a TestFlight notification when you will press the button "go".

First of all the person you invite for TestFlight has to accept to be a tester for your application.

Then they will receive an email in order to download the application TestFlight.
From there, each time you will make a new version for testing they will be notified.