# TestFlight in-app purchase still use sandbox account

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, testflight, in-app-subscription

I've read the articles/documentation/threads about the in-app purchase process in the TestFlight release.

[1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/49940), [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196372/testflight-in-app-purchases-sandbox-user-still-needed-after-passing-beta-review), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316718/sandbox-account-for-ios-test-flight-beta-testing),

They will always say that the app will use our real Apple ID but will create a sandbox environment for it. [This one](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/115031) though, is a bit different. It kind of confirms my situation right now.

It's either I don't understand that clearly or something wrong with my account setup. I always got the popup to use the sandbox account on my phone.

[image: TestFlight in-app purchase]
[image: AppStore Sandbox accounbt]
Could someone really explain to me what's happening here? I

Comment: If you are running a TestFlight build you will always get a sandbox account. You are getting a sandbox account. What's the issue exactly?

Comment: Hey @matt The issue was it asked me the sandbox account detail while I was testing a TestFlight build version of an in-app product. My understanding is it should ask my real AppStore account since that is what it says in the documentation. Maybe I do not fully understand it. That's the main question.